# New YouTube iframe code not displaying video on iPhone

Tags: iphone, iframe, youtube, mobile-safari

We added the new YouTube iframe code into our News site. The problem is the video doesn't appear on the iPhone.

Here's my [page](http://bit.ly/jCD5Gu) and code:

```
<iframe width="620" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/A2V1WTF8tp4?hl=en&fs=1&autoplay=0&hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

How can I get YouTube video to appear on the iPhone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The URL for the video might be the problem. The embedded video code goes like this

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Notice how the URL uses *embed* instead of *v*.

Comment: The class part is not necessary, I just copied it directly from the YouTube blog [http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html]

Answer (score 2):

Your problem may be that YouTube is Flash based, so embedding an iframe isn't going to work on the iPhone, which doesn't support Flash.
Try something like this instead:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/A2V1WTF8tp4?hl=en&fs=1&autoplay=0&hd=1" width="620" height="3900">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/A2V1WTF8tp4" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<!-- Fallback content -->
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A2V1WTF8tp4">
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/A2V1WTF8tp4/0.jpg" width="620" height="390" alt="Staff Gathers for Multicultural Springfest" />
</a>
</object>
```

code courtesy of: http://learningtheworld.eu/2009/youtube-embed/

Answer (score 0):

I have a subclass of UIWebView to accomplish this, and this is how it works:

(in init:)

```
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/A2V1WTF8tp4"];

CGRect theFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 300);

NSString* embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<iframe width=%i height=%i src=%@ frameborder=10 allowfullscreen></iframe>", theFrame.size.width, theFrame.size.height, url];

[self loadHTMLString: embedHTML baseURL: nil]; // this method is part of UIWebView.
```

Just ensure your "video view" is added as a subview of whichever view owns it.